# Is there a way to attach new Android Profiler to debug app process directly after build?

Tags: android, android-studio

Attaching Android Studio 3.0 Android Profiler to debug app from cold start is almost impossible, because I'd have to select process from dropdown (and start record) in very short timespan.

For profiling app cold start, is there a more convenient way?

Selecting "debug app" in android Developer Settings does not help unfortunately.

Comment: Here's a bug report for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78900696

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With Android Studio 3.2 Canary 11, you can profile your app from startup.

Just go to Run -> Edit Configurations -> Profiling Tab and check "Start recording a method trace on startup".

Here's a link to download it. https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Answer (score 6):

Well, makeshift solution because I didn't find anything better :

I set breakpoint in Application `onCreate` to make sure cold boot stops on it. This gives me enough time to set up Android Profiler and select my process. However by starting app with debugger attached, the results might be bit skewed, because debugger slows down app a little.

Seems to be the best option I have for now, but since nobody posted anything I missed, I'll try to do feature request on android tracker.

Comment: Have you found a better way? Or do you have the link to the feature request?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63799807 . You can see the reply `this feature is already in our plans` which I assume also covers this case.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, profiling on app launch is now available from Android Studio 3.2 Canary 11. https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Comment: Yes the profiler starts, but it doesn't start collecting any info. You still have to double click the cpu trace and click record, which renders it useless for cold start profiling. Despite setting the CPU profiling method in the run->edit configurations menu.

Answer (score 1):

Run -> Edit Configurations ->

[image]